# Creating an Array that creates instance of a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, instance

Hello everyone I got the following struct

```
struct Test
{
    unsigned char* c_string;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

I created a function that creates a new instance of this struct and initialize the attributes with random values like this

```
struct Test* createNewTest(){
struct Test *NewInstance = (Test * )malloc( sizeof(Test) );
NewInstance->value = rand();
```

Now I have to create a function that creates n completely initialized instances of my struct.

```
struct Test** createNewArray(unsigned int n){
};
```

Can anyone help me to do this? I dont really now how to start here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `sizeof(Test)` --> `sizeof(struct Test)`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve by assigning the pointer c_string to a random number, doesn't look to smart.  If you want to use sizeof(Test), prefix your structure with typedef and append the name to the structure.

Comment: `NewInstance->c_string = rand();` is your compiler does not complain, you actually have a problem in your environment.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong version there should not be a 

New Instance ->c_string = rand();

Comment: Break the problem down into parts rather than viewing it as one large whole - like start of, by thinking how you'd allocate the space for your array for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straightforward.  First, you'll need to allocate enough storage for `n` pointers to `struct Test`:

```
struct Test **array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);
if (!array) return array;
```

And then assign each pointer, using the function you have:

```
for (size_t i = 0;  i < n;  ++i)
    array[i] = createNewTest();
```

Wrapping it all up, you get

```
struct Test **createNewArray(size_t n)
{
    struct Test **array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);
    if (!array) return array;

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < n;  ++i)
        array[i] = createNewTest();

    return array;
}
```

Don't forget to write a matching `free()` function!

Also, consider whether you really want an array of pointers to `Test` - you may be better off with an array of `Test` objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try to explain this without giving you the answer to your assignment verbatim ...

First, you need to allocate `n` times as much memory. `malloc` can allocate any amount, so you just need to calculate the number.

Second, you need to do the same initialization, but for each entry in the array. You'll need a loop for that.

Hint: in C, a pointer to a single instance and a pointer to a dynamic array are indistinguishable. `ptr->value` is the same as `ptr[0].value`, and `ptr[1].value` is the next element in the array.